# cannot find member on object of runtimetype

Tags: json, vb.net

I am currently working on a legacy web app which uses newtonsoft.json.dll version 1.3.0 and vb.net.

I added four new fields in the application. This source code is shared by another application and it posts into my application and it breaks it.

See image for error.

[[image: Error display]]

The error is:

> Could not find member x on object of type runtimetype.

The stacktrace breaks at:

> newtonsoft.json.jsonserializer.setobjectmember(jsonreader reader,object target, type targettype, string membername)

I did some research. The folks reportedly solved such an issue by upgrading DLL version and didn't have a direct solution to fixing it via code change. I know its very old and the application is high impact any upgrade has huge ripple. However they are planning a rewrite of the application.

Can someone please share any ideas that i should pursue in order to solve this?. 
I am expected to make it quick and under pressure.

Comment: Please type the error message into your question.

Comment: The json and the code to deserialize it would be needed to come close to understanding the issue let alone answer it.

Answer (score 0):

https://smugmugc3.codeplex.com/workitem/10024

My problem is very similar to what is described in the link above. 
I am going to upgrade my version of json converter after convincing my boss and I see that is the only way out of this problem.

After which I will update this thread if I find issues.